# Optimizing Execution Time

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a loop that takes values from different files and puts them all in one file in the  format needed. My code works, the problem it takes 4 minutes to read 2 files. The following snippet from my code is the one that i think is taking the longest. I have very similar loops thorough my script. My question is if anybody can help me rewrite the code so it takes less time to run. I think there is a way of doing that with arrays I just don't know how to. Thanks.

```
for(var row = 16; row<=28;row++) { // Nested Loop checks the individual SKUs and gets the information
        //Variable "row" is for the SAF File, Not the Recap

          if( fileSheet.getRange("A"+row).isBlank()) {  //If file is out of info

            break; // break out of loop
            Logger.log("This code should never be executed")
          }

          if( !fileSheet.getRange("A"+row).isBlank()) { 

           var hValue = fileSheet.getRange("D2").getValue() ; // gets the distributor for the SAF
           recap.getRange("C"+(recap.getLastRow())).offset(1,0).setValue(hValue) ; //offset is needed to put info in the row after the last row

            var lRow = recap.getLastRow() ; // last row of the ----!RECAP!---- After Offset

           hValue = fileSheet.getRange("A"+row).getValue() ; //gets the SKU
           recap.getRange("E"+lRow).setValue(hValue) ;


           hValue = fileSheet.getRange("D"+row).getValue() ; //gets the quantity
           recap.getRange("H"+lRow).setValue(hValue) ;

           hValue = fileSheet.getRange("E"+row).getValue() ; //gets the price
           recap.getRange("G"+lRow).setValue(hValue) ;

           hValue = fileSheet.getRange("H"+row).getValue() ; // gets the 
                                                                discount%

           recap.getRange("K"+lRow).setValue(hValue) ;

            hValue = fileSheet.getRange("A2").getValue() ; //gets  the date

            recap.getRange("P"+lRow).setValue(hValue) ;

            hValue = currentFile.getUrl() //gets the url of the SAF
            recap.getRange("R"+lRow).setValue(hValue) ;
```

Comment: set the [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()) sheet data into a variable/`array[][]` before the `for` loop and then [traverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Accessing_array_elements) the data within the loop - put the values you want to set into an array and make  a call to `setValues()` after the for loop - google apps script [best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices)

Comment: Im sorry but I dont know how to do that, would you mind showing me some code?

Comment: you can [see an example here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations)

Comment: Yeah i saw that before posting i just don't see how to use it for my situation, The information from the source is not in the same order than the destination, there are also a lot of blank rows and columns in both files.Thanks anyways i guess.